# LINQ Except with RegEx in C#

Tags: c#, linq

I have two lists of strings, the first list is a list of emails, the second list is a list of possible matches which can contain wildcard characters * and/or ? (* for lazy matching and ? for single character macthing)

First List Example:

```
email1
email2
etc
```

Second List Example:

```
*@gmail.com
bob@*.com
tony??@*.com
```

I want to return a list which removes matches from the first list using the second list.

I initially looked at the Except method because it seemed like a very performant way of iterating and comparing two lists quickly. This worked well. Then I tried to integrate RegEx into the mix, then things became more complicated...

I created a custom comparer with the following in the Equals overload:
return (new Regex(x, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)).IsMatch(y);

but that didn't seem to provide the result I expected! Is there an easier way to overcome this scenario?

Comment: Please show your full code.

Comment: I'm not really sure showing the code I have will expand on the description of the problem I gave.

Comment: @Ginko showing your code shows effort at solving the problem, and not showing your effort can be interpreted by most kind of like "can anyone write this code for me". It's also usually a bit easier to fix sample code than to write it from scratch.

Comment: "I'm not really sure showing the code" - Why not?

Comment: Yes, I agree, but that is not the case here. I explained the problem clearly in English, showing a bunch of code (Other than the code I already provided) will just clog the original post and turn it into a tldr.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
var filtered = list1.Where(y => list2.Any(x => new Regex(x, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).IsMatch(y));
```

I don't think it will be particularly performant, however, so if you're checking a big list, I'd recommend looking at other ways of doing this.

This might be more performant:

```
var list1 = new List<string>();
var list2 = new List<string>();

var regex = new Regex(string.Join("|", list2.Select(l => string.Concat("(", l, ")")).ToArray()), RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
var filtered = list1.Where(l => regex.IsMatch(l));
```

Comment: You are probably best off doing something like `var regexList = list2.Select(x=>new Regex(x, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase));` so you only create the regex objects once rather than once per iteration. Also I think you need a negation and All (you are getting only the ones that match something in the regex list, my understanding is that it wants the things from the first list that don't match any of the regex).

Comment: Thanks for the response! The first did 6.8 million records in the first list and 4 items in the second list in 5 minutes, but it worked so that was great! I changed the Any to All ad added a ! to reverse the result as I needed the matches removed. The second example, the parser didn't like the dollar sign and it threw a wobbly - In too late there after Chris' reply!

Comment: @Ginko Ah, the $ may be a newer C# feature. Sorry :)

Comment: Interpolated strings! gotcha! I'm still supporting XP machines in 4.0 but maybe I should stop living in the past! haha - I changed it slightly to support the wildcards and it seems to work great! new Regex(string.Join("|", roleBasedList.Select(l => string.Concat("(", Regex.Escape(l).Replace(@"\?", ".?").Replace(@"\*", ".*?"), ")")).ToArray()), RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use `a.IsMatch(b)` in equality-based scenarios, because it does not satisfy a basic requirement to equality (symmetry). Because it requires items of different kind on both sides, it is also not transitive, and not reflexive.

The reason `Except` method is fast is that it can use hash-based matching. Unfortunately, it is not possible with regex-based matching, so you will need to deal with an O(n*r) solution (n is the number of items, r is the number of regular expressions), i.e. a `Where` condition with `All` or `Any` call to decide a match.

Answer (score 2):

No need for LINQ:

```
var list1 = new List<string> { "email1", "email2" };
string[] list2 = { "*@gmail.com", "bob@*.com", "tony??@*.com" };

var pattern = "^(" + Regex.Escape(string.Join("|", list2)).Replace("\\|", "|").Replace("\\?", ".?").Replace("\\*", ".*") + ")$"; 
var regEx = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

list1.RemoveAll(regEx.IsMatch);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response! I like the clean and simplistic approach! Emails support UTF8 now and also some ASCII characters that may conflict with regular expression specials such as: !#$%&'*+-/=?^_`{|}~. It throws a wobbly when I use some of these chars in the second list. Do you think maybe integrating RegEx.Escape into the mix would be better?

Comment: @Ginko definitely. That was my initial approach, but it was escaping more than I wanted. You can try the updated sample.

Answer (score 2):

For the huge number of records you have Expression tree would be the fastest way to achieve it, check the following code:

```
void Main()
{
    // Create EXpression parameter for the Info Type
    var parameterType = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Info), "obj");

    // Access the Email member for the Type Info in the Expression type
    var memmberExpressionProperty = Expression.Property(parameterType, "Email");

    // Regex Patterns
    HashSet<string> emailPatterns = new HashSet<string>
    {    
      @"^(.*@gmail\.com|bob@.*\.com|tony.?.?@.*\.com)$"
    };

    // Wrapping and Calling the Extension method for Regex match
    MethodInfo filtersMethodInfo = typeof(StringExtensions).GetMethod("RegexMatch", new[] { typeof(string), typeof(HashSet<string>) });

    // Create Constant Expression and supply the Email Patterns Hashset
    ConstantExpression  filtersConstantExpression = Expression.Constant(emailPatterns, typeof(HashSet<string>));

    // Create Final Expression - MethodCall Expression
    var finalExpression = Expression.Call(null, filtersMethodInfo, memmberExpressionProperty, filtersConstantExpression);

    // Compile the EXpression Lambda
    var resultFunc = Expression.Lambda<Func<Info, bool>>(finalExpression, parameterType).Compile();

    // Email Data for filtering
    List<Info> EmailInfo = new List<Info>()
   {
     new Info {Email="abcd@gmail.com"},
     new Info {Email="abcc@gmail2.com"},
     new Info {Email="vbhg@guuumail.com"},
     new Info {Email="kkkk@gmail.com"},
     new Info {Email="jjjj@gqqqmail.com"}
};

    var finalResult = EmailInfo.Where(obj => resultFunc(obj));
}

public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static bool RegexMatch(this string source, HashSet<string> patternHashset)
    {
        return source != null && patternHashset.Any(pattern => Regex.Match(source, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Success);
    }
}

public class Info
{
    public string Email { get; set;}
}
```

**Important Details**

1. `Info` is the class with list of Emails to be filtered, in your case FirstList
2. `emailPatterns` is the Regex patterns for mapping, I have copied the same from one of the answer by  @Slai, as I am not very sure about Regex
3. We create a RegexMatch as a string Extension which match with all the patterns in the Hashset supplied and provide a true result on any match
4. Compile the Expression tree and `finalResult` is the final answer, which is correct when with data I have used